# Android Firebase logEvent() uses incorrect value type

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

My Firebase analytics implementation is using `Firebase.analytics.logEvent()` to log various events.

When I send a `String` in the Bundle parameter that is all numeric characters, it is reported as a `Double` by the SDK in the logging/data. Same problem for `Int` as they are also reported as a `Double`.

eg. `"90210"` reports as a `double_value` of `90210.0`

We want them to be logged as `String` and `Int` instead of `Double`

I have debug logging on using:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <application_id>
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
```

Here is the event I'm sending:

```
Firebase.analytics.logEvent("event1", Bundle().apply {
   putString("testString", "123")
   putInt("testInt", 123)
})
```

And the data I see in the console:

```
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       param {
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         name: testInt
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         double_value: 123.0
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       }

09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       param {
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         name: testString
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         double_value: 123.0
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       }
```

What I expect to see:

```
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       param {
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         name: testInt
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         int_value: 123
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       }

09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       param {
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         name: testString
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):         string_value: "123"
09-02 06:45:12.424 V/FA-SVC  ( 2418):       }
```